# Change html list to select with input type hidden

Tags: javascript, php, html, select, hidden-field

I am redoing some code that a colleague of mine did. I wish to change his list to a more appropriate select-option drop-down list.

His php code looks like the following:

```
echo "<ul>";
echo "<li><a href='#' >Customer</a><ul>";
$count = count($Cust);
for ($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++) {
    echo "<li><a href='#' id='ddcust'><input type='hidden' value='".$Cust[$i]["label"]."'>".$Cust[$i]["label"]."</a></li>";
}
echo "</ul></li></ul>";
```

How to I change this into a select option list whilst trying to keep as much as possible of the functions handling the selection intact?

He handles the selection like this:

```
var get_cust = $('input[type="hidden"]', this).val();
```

Is it possible to create a select with the input type hidden?

I tried it like this, but it doesn't work:

```
echo "<select name='customerSelect' size='1'>";
echo "<option value=''>- Please select a customer -</option>";
$count = count($Cust);
for ($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++) {
    echo "<option id='ddcust'><input type='hidden' value='".$Cust[$i]["label"]."'>".$Cust[$i]["label"]."</option>";
}
echo "</select>";
```

Comment: You can't have child elements in option tag. so the answer is NO.

Comment: what do you want to achieve? why you want to create a select with the input type hidden?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
echo "<select name='customerSelect' size='1'>";
echo "<option value=''>- Please select a customer -</option>";
$count = count($Cust);
for ($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++) {
echo "<option value='".$Cust[$i]["label"]."'>".$Cust[$i]["label"]."</option>";
}
echo "</select>";


var get_cust = $('select[name=customerSelect]').val();
```

or

```
var get_cust = $('select[name=customerSelect] option:selected').text();
```